# Error when connect with wifi in xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin.ios

Error Domain=NEHotspotConfigurationErrorDomain Code=8 "internal error." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=internal error.}

Here is my code:

NEHotspotConfigurationManager wifiManager = new NEHotspotConfigurationManager();
            var wifiConfig = new NEHotspotConfiguration(ssid, password, false) { JoinOnce = true };

```
        wifiManager.RemoveConfiguration(ssid);
        wifiManager.ApplyConfigurationAsync(wifiConfig);
        wifiManager.ApplyConfiguration(wifiConfig, (error) =>
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error.GetType());
                Console.WriteLine($"Error while connecting to WiFi network {ssid}: {error}");
            }
        });
        return true;
```

Comment: Hi , you should detail show what you have done in project, and to explain what function you want to achieve. By the way , from shared error log, here is a similar discussion for reference.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060649/nehotspotconfigurationerrordomain-code-8-internal-error

Comment: i want to connect to wifi using ssid and password in xamarin ios so i get this error.

Comment: Okey, the first step is to set the “Enable Hotspot Configuration” entitlement in your Entitlements.plist file. Do you configure this ?

Comment: I share an answer .If be helpful , thanks for marking in advance.

Comment: Both the configuration is on but error is same :Foundation.NSErrorException: Error Domain=NEHotspotConfigurationErrorDomain Code=8 "internal error." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=internal error.}

Comment: Is the SSID within the scope of the device search?

Comment: Means hotspot is on with these ssid?

Comment: Yeah , you should use physical device to connect the wifi, and be sure the wifi can be searched .Not using emulator to do this.

Comment: yeah, wifi is in within range and i am doing with real device.

Comment: I have tried many codes but the error is same in all codes "Internal error code 8" and type of error is "Foundation.NSError".

Comment: If In ios 12, also need to set this .https://i.stack.imgur.com/JESFO.png And AppID also need to add this .

Comment: Access wifi information setting is also enabled.

Comment: Rebooting your device to have a try. Here is a previous in ios 11 occurs dicussion about this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060649/nehotspotconfigurationerrordomain-code-8-internal-error?rq=1 This probelm is strange in IOS and seems like not easy to find the final reason.

Comment: Reboot device is not worked for me.

Comment: Okey, Maybe this related to some configure of wifi .

Answer (score 1):

This is new with iOS11+ and enables your app to join a network using a known SSID. You can find the [documentation over at Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfigurationmanager). To use it, you won’t have to request access to the super-secret hotspot APIs but there’s still a little configuration required.

The first step is to set the “**Enable Hotspot Configuration**” entitlement in your Entitlements.plist file:

[image]

This entitlement must also be configured in the developer portal when creating an app ID for your application:

[image]

With these settings in place you can start connecting to a network. The code is not complicated and requires the creation of an NEHotspotConfiguration object which specifies how the network will be used. Among the configurable parameters is for example a boolean that tells iOS if you are trying to access the network just temporarily or for longer. You should [read the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfiguration) to find out what settings work best for your case. Here’s a code example:

```
var config = new NEHotspotConfiguration(ssid, password, isWep: false);
config.JoinOnce = false;
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<NSError>();
NEHotspotConfigurationManager.SharedManager.ApplyConfiguration(config, err => tcs.SetResult(err));
var error = await tcs.Task;
if (error != null)
{
    var alert = new UIAlertController
    {
        Title = "Error",
        Message = error.Description
    };
    alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
    PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
    return;
}
```

Note:If in IOS 12, you also need to set this in Entitlement :

[image]

and AppID:

[image]